# I keep getting "non static method cannot be referenced from a static context"

Tags: java

The method is supposed to accept 3 arguments - String, double, and String. And then it will return a value to be printed in the main method. How do I do this?
Here's what I did

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.JTextArea;

    public class coordinates
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {   
            double angle=0, az = 0;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello, this is the 'Bearing to Azimuth' converter.\nFirst, you must input whether the angle is from the North or from the South, input the angle, and then input whether it is East or West.", "Bearing to Azimuth converter", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            String ns = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input n for North and s for South:");
            String inputangle = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input the angle in decimal format:");
            angle = Double.parseDouble(inputangle);
            String ew = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input e for East and w for West:");

            convertToSouthAzimuth(ns, angle, ew);


            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The converted azimuth is " + az, "Bearing to Azimuth converter", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    } //end main method



        public double convertToSouthAzimuth(String ns, double angle, String ew)
        {
            double az = 0;
            if (ns.equals("n")||ns.equals("N")) {
                if (ew.equals("e")||ew.equals("E")) {az= 180+angle;}
                if(ew.equals("w")|| ew.equals("W")){az= 180-angle;}
            }
            if (ns.equals("s")||ns.equals("S")) {
                if (ew.equals("e")||ew.equals("E")) {az= 360-angle;}
                if (ew.equals("w")||ew.equals("W")) {az= angle;}
            }
            return az;
        } //end convertToSouthAzimuth method
    }
```

Comment: IMHO, you should first read Java basics about classes, how to instantiate classes, and static members. Trying finding the problem with your program after you have grasped these concepts.

Answer (score 6):

The `convertToSouthAzimuth` method hasn't been declared as `static`, so the compiler expects it to be called on an instance of that class. However, your `main` method **is** static, so there isn't an instance of that class available.

If `convertToSouthAzimuth` only works with parameters passed, and has no bearing on the current instance, then you could change it to being a static method:

```
public static double convertToSouthAzimuth(...) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
public double convertToSouthAzimuth(...) { }
```

To

```
public static double convertToSouthAzimuth(...) {}
```

Because main is a static method and you cannot call any non-static method(s) inside it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `static` keyword to your method `convertToSouthAzimuth()`since you're refering to it from your `main()`-method which in itself is a static method.

This could be circumvented, if you do **not** want to refer to it as a static, by including it in a new class.

I have, intentionally, left out the constructor of the new class.

Something like this:

```
public class AzimuthConverter {

   public double convertToSouthAzimuth(String s, Double d, String s){
       return someValue;
   }
}
```

and then do

`AzimuthConverter myConverter = new AzimuthConverter()`

and follow up with

`double myResult = myConverter.convertToSouthAzimuth(value);`

Answer (score 1):

Static methods belong to the *class*, whereas non-static methods belong on a class *instance*.

Thus you would need to do something like

```
...
new coordinates().convertToSouthAzimuth(ns, angle, ew);
...
```

or just make the `convertToSouthAzimuth(...)` method static, which is probably a better option in this particular case, since it doesn't have any bearing (pun intended) on the `coordinates` class (it could even be moved to a helper class, as @limelights suggests in another answer).

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

AS others have already answered about your error, i would like to point out another enhancement in your code. you could use [String.equalIgonreCase(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) instead of

```
        if (ns.equals("n")||ns.equals("N")) {
```

Can be

```
        if (ns.equalIgonreCase("n")) {
```